# Amazon Webservice Powershell Credentials Setup Errors

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I am trying to set up my AWS on my local machine through Windows Powershell and am getting the following error message:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey AKIAJVD4X35xxxxxx -SecretKey 8CyGJKtOtqesdroQS/IJVZwNnZSr/xxxxxxxx -StoreAs AWSarnav

Set-AWSCredentials : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey AKIAJVD4X35xxxxxx -SecretKey 8CyGJKt ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AWSCredential], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Amazon.PowerShell.Common.SetCredentialCmdlet
```

Comment: You should probably delete that access key